# How can I avoid storing database credentials in multiple places in the code?

Tags: php, class, global-variables, database-connection, connection-string

The user 'Chacha102' posted the following code in response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2777325/1288274) question back in 2010. I like his code (displayed below), but would like suggestions on how to avoid having the database connection credentials appearing in multiple places in the code.

Here is his code:

```
$cb_db = new cb_db(USER, PASSWORD, NAME, HOST);
$cb_user = new cb_user($cb_db);

class cb_user {
    public __construct(cb_db $database)
    {
        $this->database = $database
    }

    protected function find_by_sql( $sql ) {

        $this->database = new cb_db(USER, PASSWORD, NAME, HOST);
        $result_set = $cb_db->query( $sql );

        $object_array = array();
        while( $row = $cb_db->fetch_array( $result_set ) ) {
            $object_array[] = self::instantiate( $row );
        }
        return $object_array;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I will have many classes and functions and don't want to have the username a password hard coded into each of them. I'd prefer it if when necessary it can be updated in just one place.

What is the best way to accomplish this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not have a "config.php" which declares all the variables you will use, such as username, database, server, other settings maybe relevant to the site etc.

Comment: I do have that currently, it also sets up the connection and stores it as an object in a variable. I then have to declare it as a global, in order to use it in a class or pass it in to each function as an argument.

The thing is in the post I originally linked to above, this was considered not best practice. Using the config.php as you suggested, wouldn't I still have to pass the variables in and create the connection each time it's needed?

Comment: No, if its global its available for use..  Many systems use this, I do think the file should sit outside the accessible web tree if possible, for security, but, no, you can just include it by default and then all the setting are there. Auto connecting unless you need it would be a waste

Comment: the way i do is to make these variables as constant and include them in my models(db fetch functions) instead of making them global